# git + ftp upload

Tags: git, ftp

I have a beginner question.

If I have 2 branches, master and testbranch and  I switch to testbranch and then via FTP upload a new file, does that affect both master and testbranch?

I tried doing that and the changes show up in both master and testbranch when I run "git st".

Is there any way to hide the changes from master or is that just how git works?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean _download_ a new file? I'm sort of confused.

Comment: I have the following setup:  putty for ssh and git to my dev and live server.  filezilla for download and upload file (after editing).  I track changes on my dev server and then push to remove repository and do a pull from my live server to bring changes to the live website.   Just wondering if my setup is correct.

Comment: oh an if on putty i switch to "Testbranch" and then via FTP, I edit somefile.php, will that change show up in both testbranch and master or just testbranch?

Comment: @user1062354 if you edit a tracked file, git will prevent branch change to avoid losing your modifications

Comment: @user1062354, I think what you're seeing is the extreme flexibility of git. You could make a change in your testbranch, then switch to master and commit it there if the branches are close enough. It's completely up to you. It's not actually *in the branch* unless you commit it.

Comment: Also, how exactly are you doing the push/pull? When pulling from the server you have to be careful you're pulling the correct branch, or you might accidentally get the wrong one.

Comment: Push pull is done via ssh only.  I tried using tortoisgit locally, but there's no need since I always upload the changes to my test server anyway, so it is a lot more manageable via command line (ssh)

Comment: @user1062354, I mean how exactly do you do the push? Do you specify the branch you're pushing to or do you assume that the `master` branch on the remote is same as the branch you're pushing from? There are ways of pushing your repo while mirroring all your branches, and there are ways of just pushing branch heads one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a file that is untracked, you can still checkout other branches, the file will stay. Imagine the opposite, if Git deletes it when switching branches, the file would be lost since it was committed!

However `git status` will still say that the file is untracked, but it doesn't mean that your branches are affected. It's just Git telling you that the state between your branches record and the working copy is different.

Then you have two options:

- Add and commit the file: when switching to `master` it will be removed, and reappear when switching back to `testbranch`
- Don't commit, just stash the state and go back to `master`:

```
 git stash --include-untracked
 #file is saved in a temporary place, and removed
 git checkout master
 #do stuff...
 git checkout testbranch
 # git stash pop
 #file is restored
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like when you say "switch" you mean you're using the `git checkout` command. This command switches between committed versions in your repository. If you "FTP upload" a new file (I'm assuming you mean add files to your sandbox, or overwrite existing files), it wouldn't affect the committed version unless you commit it. Do you plan to commit the file you placed into the sandbox (I presume) by means of your FTP upload? Because that's the only way it could affect the branch.

In general, you cannot affect the commits on your `master` branch while you're working on your `testbranch`. Commits will stay exactly as committed unless you `rebase` them, or otherwise modify the repository itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the date of ftp upload you can use [`git whatchanged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged) for retrieve a list of modify files.

Your command can seems like something like this :

```
git whatchanged --since 'dd/mm/yyyy' --until 'dd/mm/yyyy' --oneline --name-only --pretty=format: | sort | uniq
```